# Solr 9.3 without SSL on RHEL 8.8 - cannot create core

Tags: java, solr, rhel

We recently upgraded several servers from RHEL 7.9 to RHEL 8.8 and are now attempting to perform clean installations of Solr 9.3 with OpenJDK 11. RHEL is running in FIPS mode with SELinux enabled but our particular Solr environment does not require any crypto, so we've disabled FIPS and SSL within Solr by adding the following to /etc/default/solr.in.sh -

SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -Dcom.redhat.fips=false"

SOLR_SSL_ENABLED=false

--

Solr itself starts normally but attempting to create a core errors out with this -

> ERROR: java.lang.IllegalStateException: /var/solr/NONE is not a valid keystore
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: /var/solr/NONE is not a valid keystore
> at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.Http2SolrClient.createHttpClient(Http2SolrClient.java:290)
> at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.Http2SolrClient.(Http2SolrClient.java:180)
> at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.Http2SolrClient$Builder.build(Http2SolrClient.java:1052)
> at org.apache.solr.cli.SolrCLI.getSolrClient(SolrCLI.java:426)
> at org.apache.solr.cli.CreateCoreTool.runImpl(CreateCoreTool.java:109)
> at org.apache.solr.cli.ToolBase.runTool(ToolBase.java:52)
> at org.apache.solr.cli.SolrCLI.main(SolrCLI.java:156)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: /var/solr/NONE is not a valid keystore
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.CertificateUtils.getKeyStore(CertificateUtils.java:45)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.loadKeyStore(SslContextFactory.java:1121)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.load(SslContextFactory.java:291)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.doStart(SslContextFactory.java:213)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:121)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ClientConnector.doStart(ClientConnector.java:376)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:121)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:121)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.client.http.HttpClientTransportOverHTTP2.doStart(HttpClientTransportOverHTTP2.java:100)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:121)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient.doStart(HttpClient.java:232)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
> at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.Http2SolrClient.createHttpClient(Http2SolrClient.java:287)
> 6 more

--

With SSL explicitly disabled, we would have expected all SSL-specific requirements to be ignored, but seems like they are not. The same process works as expected in our old environment with Solr 8.8. Are there other parameters or configuration files we've missed which may be specific to Solr 9.x?

To clarify - Solr itself starts without issues and bypasses FIPS requirements as expected. It's only core creation which behaves this way.

Thanks for any insight.